# Domain Migration - SharePoint Online User Permissions Migration

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, domain

We are migrating users from one internal domain to another within our AD Forest. 
 We can use Move-SPUser in SharePoint 2013 upwards and $farm.MigrateUserAccount( $*.oldlogin, $*.newlogin, $false ) for other SharePoint Farms.

What is the correct way to migrate a users permissions from one profile to another in SharePoint Online for all SharePoint sites?  (i.e. the user is getting a new profile in AD which is synced with AAD in Azure).